# Need a better way to keep test code out of production code - slf4jtesting

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, slf4j

I'm using [`com.portingle:slf4jtesting:1.1.3`](https://github.com/portingle/slf4jtesting) to aid testing of some logging functionality.

My problem is that the devs at `com.portingle` are [strong advocates of dependency injection](https://github.com/portingle/slf4jtesting/issues/8) and suggest only dependency injection for utilising their `slf4jtesting::ILoggerFactory` utility (an implementation of slf4j which stores up the log entries for easy testing and validation).

With dependency injection, I *could* just create my slf4j loggers in my classes like this and inject either a production or test `LoggerFactory`:

```
import org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

public class Example1 {

    private final Logger logger;

    public Example1(ILoggerFactory lf) {
        this.logger = lf.getLogger(Example1.class.getName());
    }

    public void aMethodThatLogs() {
        logger.info("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Reasonable enough but I've got a legacy app and all my loggers are already coded and used sometimes in static code blocks / methods, so standard DI constructor injection won't work.

Currently I am doing this:

```
private static final Logger log = LoggingUtils.getLogger(
        RequestLoggingFilter.class);
```

and `LoggingUtils` looks like this:

```
public class LoggingUtils {

    private LoggingUtils() {
    }

    private static ILoggerFactory iLoggerFactory =
            LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

    /**
     * We don't want to call this in production.
     */
    public static void switchToTestLogging() {
        iLoggerFactory = Settings.instance().enableAll().buildLogging();
    }

    /**
     * Return logger for a class, of whatever implementation is running,
     * e.g. test or prod logger.
     *
     * @param loggingClass the class doing the logging
     * @return logger
     */
    public static Logger getLogger(Class loggingClass) {
        return iLoggerFactory.getLogger(loggingClass.getName());
    }
```

So in tests, I can switch to `slf4jtesting::ILoggerFactory` with a call to my `switchToTestLogging()`, but the end result is that I have `slf4jtesting` code in my production code.

Alternatively, I could make the `iLoggerFactory` public so that the tests can just replace it when necessary, but it would be bad practice to allow any production code to do that.

Lastly, I could [use reflection to hack the private `ILoggerFactory` instance](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html) in my `LoggingUtils` class and assign a test `LoggerFactory` during testing:

```
@BeforeAll
public static void setupLogging()
        throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field loggerFactoryField =
            LoggingUtils.class.getDeclaredField("iLoggerFactory");
    loggerFactoryField.setAccessible(true);
    loggerFactoryField.set(null,
        Settings.instance().enableAll().buildLogging());
}
```

but that's also not exactly 'best practice'.

Is there any way to keep the `ILoggerFactory` instance private, avoid reflection and keep the test libraries out of production?

Comment: While not a  big fan of static coupling, you can remove `switchToTestLogging` altogether and in testing mock the factory method to return the desired logger when invoked. PowerMockito should be able to let you mock static members.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a big fan of static coupling, but technically, you are focussing too much on implementation concerns.

You can remove `switchToTestLogging` altogether

```
public class LoggingUtils {

    private LoggingUtils() {
    }

    private static ILoggerFactory iLoggerFactory;

    /**
     * Return logger for a class
     *
     * @param loggingClass the class doing the logging
     * @return logger
     */
    public static Logger getLogger(Class loggingClass) {
        //Lazy loading.
        if(iLoggerFactory == null) {
            iLoggerFactory = LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        }
        return iLoggerFactory.getLogger(loggingClass.getName());
    }
}
```

and in testing mock the factory method to return the desired logger when invoked.

PowerMockito should be able to let you mock static members.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(LoggingUtils.class) //<-- important
public class SomeTest {
    @Test
    public void someTestMethod() {
        //Arrange
        //get the logger used in testing
        ILoggerFactory testLoggerFactory = Settings.instance().enableAll().buildLogging();
        //set up util for mocking
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(LoggingUtils.class);
        //setup mocked member
        Mockito.when(LoggingUtils.getLogger(any(Class.class)))
            .thenAnswer(i -> testLoggerFactory.getLogger(i.getArguments()[0].getName()));

        //Act
        //call subject under test that is coupled to LoggingUtils

        //Assert
        //...
    }
}
```

The `LoggingUtils` is now only concerned with production concerns, and PowerMockito allows you to stub test loggers whenever `LoggingUtils.getLogger` is invoked while exercising tests.

*Disclaimer: This has not been tested. Provided based on my recollection of the framework.*

With that done I would strongly advise refactoring your code to follow my SOLID practices that would make your code cleaner and more maintainable. Hacks like these are code smells and a clear indicator of poor design. Just because there are tools that allow a work around does not take away from the poor design choices made.